# Newsletter error: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: codeigniter

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
>
> Filename: views/editnewsletters.php
>
> Line Number: 55
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\companygiondaci\application\views\editnewsletters.php
>   Line: 55 Function: _error_handler
>
> File: C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\companygiondaci\application\controllers\Cpages.php
>   Line: 533 Function: view
>
> File: C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\companygiondaci\index.php
>   Line: 315 Function: require_once

**views/editnewsletters.php**

```
<?php if($newsl) { ?>
                    <?php foreach ($newsl as $newsl_item): ?>

                    <table border="0" style="width: 100%; height: 90px;">
                        <tr>
                            <td>Newsletter Name:</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="newsletter" value="<?php echo $newsl_item->newsl_name; ?>"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Newsletter Content:</td>
                            <td><textarea><?php echo $newsl_item->newsl_content; ?></textarea></td>
                        </tr>   
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td><input type="submit" class="edit" value="SUBMIT"/></td>
                        </tr>   
                    </table>

                    <?php endforeach; }?>
```

---

Line 55:

---

**controllers/cpages.php**

```
public function editnewsletter() { 


    $data['success_message'] = '';  

    $newsl_id = $this->uri->segment(3);

    $data['newsl'] = $this->Mpages->update_newsletter($newsl_id);

    $this->load->view('editnewsletters', $data); 


}
```

**models/mpages.php**

```
public function update_newsletter($newsl_id)
{

    $data = array(
        'newsl_name' => $this->input->post('newsl_name'),
        'newsl_date' => $this->input->post('newsl_date'),
        'newsl_content' => $this->input->post('newsl_content')
    );

    $this->db->where('newsl_id', $newsl_id);
    $query = $this->db->update('newsletter', $data);

    return $query;  

}
```

Comment: From the code you provided It seems that you're returing the updated query result and I doubt there is no dataset rows (ie)result() in it... can you echo $query inside mpages and show the o/p

Comment: perhaps echo $query is 1.  I see a "1" on between pages.

Answer (score 0):

Because your update query return boolean value. If you update successfully query then your **$query** variable return TRUE. If you return your updated row from table then add this code.

```
$this->db->where('id', $newsl_id);
$query = $this->db->get('newsletter');
$data['newsl'] = $query->row();
```

Comment: what to return?

Comment: return boolean value

Comment: how?  like return $data['newsl']; ?